# CakePHP Multilanguage website's seo. Same url with same content, but different interface

Tags: cakephp, seo, multilingual

Suppose I have an Armenian website(content(without interface related words) is only in Armenian), but I want the interface to be available also in Russian and in English. It happens that for these different languages, in Cakephp I will have the same url and the same(Armenian) content, but different interface. like

example.com/some-url          [for english]

```
  menu -> Home
  content -> some armenian text
```

example.com/some-url          [for russian]

```
  menu -> [Home in russian]
  content - some armenian text
```

example.com/some-url          [for armenian]

```
  menu -> [Home in armenian]
  content -> some armenian text
```

So, I wanted to ask whether this is ok for seo, because search engine will see these same url-s with slightly different words from the interface part.

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of having two different languages in the same document?

Comment: I think, that some Armenian people would prefer English and especially Russian interface, in order to more easily navigate the site.

Comment: If they understand Armenian content, they understand Armenian navigation. If they can't understand even navigation, there's no chance they'll understand the content

Comment: Yes you are right, they understand Armenian content and Armenian navidation, but, it is if they prefer Russian navigation

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, the "interface" is mainly back office (administration) so you don't really have to worry about search engines.

To me, it doesn't make much sense to have an Armenian-only site with multiple "interface" languages, because the user has to understand Armenian to work with it. Anyway for truly multilingual sites (ie the language of the page depends on some HTTP request parameter) my suggestion is to go against that convention and using different URLs for different languages: not because that gives some proved advantage from the SEO perspective, but because it dramatically speeds up testability and hence development time.

Comment: Raffaele, thanks for the answer, by interface I mean,  menu items, and stuff like that, that is visible for users(cause administration part is completely invisible) such as - Home, about us, contacts, and couple of other words.

Comment: This is pointless. If users see a Russian word, they expect Russian content. I never found a site working like this

Comment: here is an example. [nayiri.com](http://www.nayiri.com/search?l=en&dt=HY_HY&query=%D5%AF%D5%A1%D5%BF%D5%A1%D6%80%D5%A5%D5%AC)

Comment: No, that is a plain multilingual site: the same *About* page can be seen in [English](http://www.nayiri.com/about?l=en), [Armenian](http://www.nayiri.com/about?l=hy_LB) and [German](http://www.nayiri.com/about?l=de). It has a "special" page (named *Dictionary* in English locale) whose content depends on the business request

Comment: See, if you change language in mentioned url, regardless of the language the section under the word - "Dictionary", always is in Armenian(as it is armenian-armenian explanation), though menu items and words near the search box change according to the selected language

Comment: It's what I said: a plain multilingual site with a **special page** called "Dictionary" whose content depends on the **business request** and not on the user's preferred locale

Comment: ok, see this two links of the same page [link-arm](http://www.nayiri.com/search?l=hy_LB&dt=HY_HY&query=%D5%AF%D5%A1%D5%BF%D5%A1%D6%80%D5%A5%D5%AC) and [link-eng](http://www.nayiri.com/search?l=en&dt=HY_HY&query=%D5%AF%D5%A1%D5%BF%D5%A1%D6%80%D5%A5%D5%AC), on this two links second part of the page is the same, isn't it bad for seo

Comment: No, because that's what the page is for (it's a dictionary). Is your site a dictionary, too?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18928/discussion-between-davo-and-raffaele)